# when compressing a sas dataset increases its size?

Tags: linux, sas

I had written a code which creates SAS dataset with compress=yes option. That said the resultant datasets is getting compressed with an increased size as seen in log

```
1374      +proc sql;
1375      +   create table seg.KRG_EO_PVS_CUST_PROD_&op_cyc.
1376      +   (
1377      +      COMPRESS = YES
1378      +   ) as
1379      +   select
^L32                                                         The SAS System                            02:15 Thursday, August 20, 2015

1380      +      W6DFFTE1.DIB_CUST_ID length = 8
1381      +         format = 15.
1382      +         informat = 15.
1383      +         label = 'The logical customer id',
1384      +      W6DFFTE1.DIB_PROD_ID length = 8
1385      +         format = 15.
1386      +         informat = 15.
1387      +         label = 'The product id',
1388      +      case when W5TM24S0.OFFER_FLAG = "1" then "1"      else "0"   end as OFFER_FLAG length = 1,
1389      +      sum(W6DFFTE1.TOT_QUANTITY ) as TOT_QUANTITY length = 8
1390      +         format = 10.
1391      +         informat = 5.
1392      +         label = 'Number of items purchased'
1393      +   from
1394      +      work.W6DFFTE1 left join
1395      +      work.W5TM24S0
1396      +         on
1397      +         (
1398      +            W5TM24S0.DIB_STORE_ID = W6DFFTE1.DIB_STORE_ID
1399      +            and W5TM24S0.DIB_SCAN_ID = W6DFFTE1.DIB_SCAN_ID
1400      +         )
1401      +   group by
1402      +      W6DFFTE1.DIB_CUST_ID,
1403      +      W6DFFTE1.DIB_PROD_ID,
1404      +      W5TM24S0.OFFER_FLAG
1405      +   ;
NOTE: Compressing data set SEG.KRG_EO_PVS_CUST_PROD_20150701 increased size by 43.27 percent.
      Compressed is 1961732 pages; un-compressed would require 1369265 pages.
NOTE: Table SEG.KRG_EO_PVS_CUST_PROD_20150701 created, with 346423801 rows and 4 columns.
```

I just want to know what are the probable reasons for this to happen

Answer (score 4):

SAS compression is pretty primitive and `compress=yes` just lets SAS save disk space by not writing actual bytes of data for unused length in character variables.  It looks like your data is three numeric variables, plus a one-character-long variable.  This is not much to work with, plus it would have to add whatever formatting overhead is involved with a compressed file.

If you need to compress files for medium or long term storage, you're much better off using a separate zip or tar utility.

EDIT:  I don't mean to disparage SAS compression.  I believe the designers were more concerned with preserving relatively fast disk access than with with providing actual zip-style compression.